# HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery: Color "table"/"grid"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

I am trying to build a color table just like MS Office font color grid. What is the best way to do it? Table, div or ul?

I have currently used a div but I am struggling to place it with in a ul which is my menu.

### HTML

```
<div id="color">

<table id="colorgrid">

    <tr>

        <td class="cell" style="background-color: #FFFF00;"></td>

        <td class="cell" style="background-color: #7CFC00;"></td>

        <td class="cell" style="background-color: #40E0D0;"></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td class="cell" style="background-color: #9400D3;"></td>

        <td class="cell" style="background-color: #FF0000;"></td>

        <td class="cell" style="background-color: #FF00FF;"></td>

    </tr>

</table> <!--End of colorgrid -->
```

### CSS

```
#colorgrid{

width: 85px;

height: 45px;

display: none;

position: absolute;

z-index: 3;
```

}

.row{

}

.cell{

```
float: left;

border: 1pt gray solid;

margin: 1px;

overflow: hidden;

width: 20px;

height: 20px;
```

}

### JS/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){       

$('#btn').click(function(){

    $('.backdrop').css('display', 'block');

    $('#colorgrid').css('display', 'block');


    $('.backdrop').click(function(){

        $('#colorgrid').css('display', 'none');

        $('.backdrop').css('display', 'none');

    });



    $('.cell').click(function(){

        var color = $(this).css('background-color');

        alert(color);

        $('#colorgrid').css('display', 'none');

        $('.backdrop').css('display', 'none');

    });

});
```

This code works, I just want an opinion, whats the best way to skin this cat? :-)

P.S. btn is in a li

[image]

Thanks,

drjay

Comment: And...what does the Microsoft Office font-color grid look like?

Comment: Don't ask him that... he's gonna print all the code! :P

Comment: For your markup you can use a table as you are indeed showing tabular data (a table of colours). So I think in this context table is the option.

Comment: @David Thomas Check the main post. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

Color pickers are now natively [supported in HTML5](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color) (Chrome, Firefox and Opera), and can be achieved using the input type `color`.

[Updated demo using HTML5](http://jsfiddle.net/ajumP/105/)

## Original

So, this question really intrigued me, mainly because it looked fun, so I decided to create a little colour palette type tool using jQuery. The setup is pretty straight forward, and the aim is to make it as dynamic as possible by using an array of colour objects that contain both the `name` ([HTML colour names](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp)), and the `hex`. The actual click event itself doesn't do anything clever apart from set the colour an a `div` which has a specific class.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/ajumP/1/)

Here is the setup:

### HTML

```
​<ul></ul>
<div class="activeColour"></div>​​​​​​​
```

### CSS

```
ul
{
    width: 125px;
}
li
{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25px;
}
.activeColour
{
    clear: both;
    height: 25px;
    width: 125px;        
}
```

### ​JavaScript - Part 1, the colours array

```
// define the colours
var colours = [
    { name: 'Yellow', hex: '#FFFF00' },
    { name: 'LawnGreen', hex: '#7CFC00' },
    { name: 'Aqua', hex: '#00FFFF' },
    { name: 'Fuchsia', hex: '#FF00FF' },
    { name: 'Blue', hex: '#0000FF' },
    { name: 'Red', hex: '#FF0000' },
    { name: 'DarkBlue', hex: '#00008B' },
    { name: 'DarkCyan', hex: '#008B8B' },
    { name: 'DarkGreen', hex: '#006400' },
    { name: 'DarkMagenta', hex: '#8B008B' },
    { name: 'DarkRed', hex: '#8B0000' },
    { name: 'DarkGoldenRod', hex: '#B8860B' },
    { name: 'DarkGray', hex: '#A9A9A9' },
    { name: 'LightGray', hex: '#D3D3D3' },
    { name: 'Black', hex: '#000000' }
];
```

### JavaScript - Part 2, clicky!

```
$(function()
{
    $('li').live('click', function()
    {
         $('.activeColour').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));       
    });

    var $palette = $('ul');
    for (var i = 0; i < colours.length; i++)
    {
        $palette.append($('<li />').css('background-color', colours[i].hex));
    }
});
​
```

Comment: Brilliant idea. I'll try this out over the weekend. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

From a validation point of view having there is nothing wrong with a DIV element inside an LI.

What exactly is the problem your experiencing?

Using table as a layout for the purpose is perfectly fine, although an older method it will serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit with Richard's solution ..
ES6, tooltips & no JQuery

```js
const colours = [
  { name:'white', hex:'#FFFFFF' },
  { name:'snow', hex:'#FFFAFA' },
  { name:'honeydew', hex:'#F0FFF0' },
  { name:'mintcream', hex:'#F5FFFA' },
  { name:'azure', hex:'#F0FFFF' },
  { name:'aliceblue', hex:'#F0F8FF' },
  { name:'ghostwhite', hex:'#F8F8FF' },
  { name:'whitesmoke', hex:'#F5F5F5' },
  { name:'seashell', hex:'#FFF5EE' },
  { name:'beige', hex:'#F5F5DC' },
  { name:'oldlace', hex:'#FDF5E6' },
  { name:'floralwhite', hex:'#FFFAF0' },
  { name:'ivory', hex:'#FFFFF0' },
  { name:'antiquewhite', hex:'#FAEBD7' },
  { name:'linen', hex:'#FAF0E6' },
  { name:'lavenderblush', hex:'#FFF0F5' },
  { name:'mistyrose', hex:'#FFE4E1' },
  { name:'gainsboro', hex:'#DCDCDC' },
  { name:'lightgray', hex:'#D3D3D3' },
  { name:'silver', hex:'#C0C0C0' },
  { name:'darkgray', hex:'#A9A9A9' },
  { name:'gray', hex:'#808080' },
  { name:'dimgray', hex:'#696969' },
  { name:'lightslategray', hex:'#778899' },
  { name:'slategray', hex:'#708090' },
  { name:'darkslategray', hex:'#2F4F4F' },
  { name:'black', hex:'#000000' },
  { name:'cornsilk', hex:'#FFF8DC' },
  { name:'blanchedalmond', hex:'#FFEBCD' },
  { name:'bisque', hex:'#FFE4C4' },
  { name:'navajowhite', hex:'#FFDEAD' },
  { name:'wheat', hex:'#F5DEB3' },
  { name:'burlywood', hex:'#DEB887' },
  { name:'tan', hex:'#D2B48C' },
  { name:'rosybrown', hex:'#BC8F8F' },
  { name:'sandybrown', hex:'#F4A460' },
  { name:'goldenrod', hex:'#DAA520' },
  { name:'peru', hex:'#CD853F' },
  { name:'chocolate', hex:'#D2691E' },
  { name:'saddlebrown', hex:'#8B4513' },
  { name:'sienna', hex:'#A0522D' },
  { name:'brown', hex:'#A52A2A' },
  { name:'maroon', hex:'#800000' },
  { name:'lightyellow', hex:'#FFFFE0' },
  { name:'lemonchiffon', hex:'#FFFACD' },
  { name:'lightgoldenrodyellow', hex:'#FAFAD2' },
  { name:'papayawhip', hex:'#FFEFD5' },
  { name:'moccasin', hex:'#FFE4B5' },
  { name:'peachpuff', hex:'#FFDAB9' },
  { name:'palegoldenrod', hex:'#EEE8AA' },
  { name:'khaki', hex:'#F0E68C' },
  { name:'darkkhaki', hex:'#BDB76B' },
  { name:'yellow', hex:'#FFFF00' },
  { name:'lightsalmon', hex:'#FFA07A' },
  { name:'salmon', hex:'#FA8072' },
  { name:'darksalmon', hex:'#E9967A' },
  { name:'lightcoral', hex:'#F08080' },
  { name:'indianred', hex:'#CD5C5C' },
  { name:'crimson', hex:'#DC143C' },
  { name:'firebrick', hex:'#B22222' },
  { name:'red', hex:'#FF0000' },
  { name:'darkred', hex:'#8B0000' },
  { name:'coral', hex:'#FF7F50' },
  { name:'tomato', hex:'#FF6347' },
  { name:'orangered', hex:'#FF4500' },
  { name:'gold', hex:'#FFD700' },
  { name:'orange', hex:'#FFA500' },
  { name:'darkorange', hex:'#FF8C00' },
  { name:'lawngreen', hex:'#7CFC00' },
  { name:'chartreuse', hex:'#7FFF00' },
  { name:'limegreen', hex:'#32CD32' },
  { name:'lime', hex:'#00FF00' },
  { name:'forestgreen', hex:'#228B22' },
  { name:'green', hex:'#008000' },
  { name:'darkgreen', hex:'#006400' },
  { name:'greenyellow', hex:'#ADFF2F' },
  { name:'yellowgreen', hex:'#9ACD32' },
  { name:'springgreen', hex:'#00FF7F' },
  { name:'mediumspringgreen', hex:'#00FA9A' },
  { name:'lightgreen', hex:'#90EE90' },
  { name:'palegreen', hex:'#98FB98' },
  { name:'darkseagreen', hex:'#8FBC8F' },
  { name:'mediumseagreen', hex:'#3CB371' },
  { name:'seagreen', hex:'#2E8B57' },
  { name:'olive', hex:'#808000' },
  { name:'darkolivegreen', hex:'#556B2F' },
  { name:'olivedrab', hex:'#6B8E23' },
  { name:'lightcyan', hex:'#E0FFFF' },
  { name:'cyan', hex:'#00FFFF' },
  { name:'aqua', hex:'#00FFFF' },
  { name:'aquamarine', hex:'#7FFFD4' },
  { name:'mediumaquamarine', hex:'#66CDAA' },
  { name:'paleturquoise', hex:'#AFEEEE' },
  { name:'turquoise', hex:'#40E0D0' },
  { name:'mediumturquoise', hex:'#48D1CC' },
  { name:'darkturquoise', hex:'#00CED1' },
  { name:'lightseagreen', hex:'#20B2AA' },
  { name:'cadetblue', hex:'#5F9EA0' },
  { name:'darkcyan', hex:'#008B8B' },
  { name:'teal', hex:'#008080' },
  { name:'powderblue', hex:'#B0E0E6' },
  { name:'lightblue', hex:'#ADD8E6' },
  { name:'lightskyblue', hex:'#87CEFA' },
  { name:'skyblue', hex:'#87CEEB' },
  { name:'deepskyblue', hex:'#00BFFF' },
  { name:'lightsteelblue', hex:'#B0C4DE' },
  { name:'dodgerblue', hex:'#1E90FF' },
  { name:'cornflowerblue', hex:'#6495ED' },
  { name:'steelblue', hex:'#4682B4' },
  { name:'royalblue', hex:'#4169E1' },
  { name:'blue', hex:'#0000FF' },
  { name:'mediumblue', hex:'#0000CD' },
  { name:'darkblue', hex:'#00008B' },
  { name:'navy', hex:'#000080' },
  { name:'midnightblue', hex:'#191970' },
  { name:'mediumslateblue', hex:'#7B68EE' },
  { name:'slateblue', hex:'#6A5ACD' },
  { name:'darkslateblue', hex:'#483D8B' },
  { name:'lavender', hex:'#E6E6FA' },
  { name:'thistle', hex:'#D8BFD8' },
  { name:'plum', hex:'#DDA0DD' },
  { name:'violet', hex:'#EE82EE' },
  { name:'orchid', hex:'#DA70D6' },
  { name:'fuchsia', hex:'#FF00FF' },
  { name:'magenta', hex:'#FF00FF' },
  { name:'mediumorchid', hex:'#BA55D3' },
  { name:'mediumpurple', hex:'#9370DB' },
  { name:'blueviolet', hex:'#8A2BE2' },
  { name:'darkviolet', hex:'#9400D3' },
  { name:'darkorchid', hex:'#9932CC' },
  { name:'darkmagenta', hex:'#8B008B' },
  { name:'purple', hex:'#800080' },
  { name:'indigo', hex:'#4B0082' },
  { name:'pink', hex:'#FFC0CB' },
  { name:'lightpink', hex:'#FFB6C1' },
  { name:'hotpink', hex:'#FF69B4' },
  { name:'deeppink', hex:'#FF1493' },
  { name:'palevioletred', hex:'#DB7093' },
  { name:'mediumvioletred', hex:'#C71585' }
];

const palette = document.getElementById('palette'), nameSpan = document.getElementById('name'), hexSpan=document.getElementById('hex');

palette.onclick = e => {
  const li = e.target;
  nameSpan.innerHTML=li.dataset.name;
  hexSpan.innerHTML=li.dataset.hex;
  if (palette.active) palette.active.className = palette.active.className.replace(' active', '');
  palette.active=li;
  li.className+=' active';
};

colours.forEach(color => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.title = color.name;
  li.style.backgroundColor = color.hex;
  li.dataset.name = color.name;
  li.dataset.hex = color.hex;
  palette.appendChild(li);
});
```

```css
#palette {
  width: 500px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#palette li {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}

#palette li.active {
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div height="100%" width="100%">
  Name: <span id="name"></span>&emsp;Hex: <span id="hex"></span>
  <ul id="palette"></ul>
</div>
```